# MySQL query returns invalid resource but no error

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

So I've got this super long query that I've been debugging.  I originally received an error that column s.name and all the other JOIN columns are not in the "field list", so after some googling I was able to fix that error by putting them in double quotes.  So now the query returns a resource without an error, but the resource is empty.

Now what I get from the echos after the statement is "Resource id #4 Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/beta/index.php on line 143 0"

Here is the query and surrounding functions:

```
<?php /* other functions preceding */ $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "");
    $cur_user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $ufriends = explode(';', $cur_user['friends']);
    $ufsql = trim(implode(',',$ufriends),',');
    $uevents = explode(';', $cur_user['events']);
    $uesql = trim(implode(',',$uevents),',');
    $urequests = explode(';', $cur_user['requests']);
    $ursql = trim(implode(',',$urequests),',');
    if (!empty($ufriends)) {
        $time1 = microtime();
        $megaresult = mysql_query("
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, NULL AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 1 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                WHERE update_type='10'
                LIMIT 1
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, NULL AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 as ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS su ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                WHERE update_type='10'
                LIMIT 1,9
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN users AS t ON (\"t.uid\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='2'
                AND
                    ( target_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                OR
                (
                    ( target_id IN (" . $cur_user['uid'] . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                )
                OR
                (
                    ( target_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $cur_user['uid'] . ") )
                )
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN users AS t ON (\"t.uid\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='4'
                AND
                (
                    ( target_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                )
                OR
                (
                    ( target_id IN (" . $cur_user['uid'] . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                )
                OR
                (
                    ( target_id IN (" . $ufsql . ") )
                AND
                    ( source_id IN (" . $cur_user['uid'] . ") )
                )
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN events AS t ON (\"t.id\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='3'
                AND
                target_id IN (" . $uesql . ")
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN events AS t ON (\"t.id\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='3'
                AND
                target_id IN (" . $ursql . ")
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN events AS t ON (\"t.id\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='5'
                AND
                target_id IN (" . $ursql . ")
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT \"s.name\" AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN users AS s ON (\"s.uid\"=recent_updates.source_id)
                INNER JOIN events AS t ON (\"t.id\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE update_type='11'
                AND
                (
                    target_id IN (" . $uesql . ")
                OR
                    target_id IN (" . $ursql . ")
                )
                AND
                (
                    source_id IN (" . $ufsql . ")
                )
                LIMIT 0,10
            )
            UNION
            ( SELECT NULL AS source_name, \"t.name\" AS target_name, recent_updates.*, 2 AS ORD FROM recent_updates
                INNER JOIN events AS t ON (\"t.id\"=recent_updates.target_id)
                WHERE public != 0 LIMIT 0,10
            )
            ORDER BY ORD ASC, time_un DESC");
        echo $megaresult;
        $feed = mysql_fetch_array($megaresult);
        echo mysql_error();
        $time2 = microtime();
        echo implode('##', $feed);
        echo mysql_num_rows($megaresult);
        echo mysql_info($con);
/* brackets closed, etc */ ?>
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with putting the aliased columns in double quotes.  I had a previous version of this query which didn't include any of the JOIN parts which worked perfectly fine, I uploaded it to pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/upifa7VJ

### EDIT:

Well this is embarrassing... I was right to suspect that the quotes were causing the problem (thanks @andrewtweber!), but the error I was getting without the quotes was due to a typo in the second SELECT statement, INNER JOIN users AS **su** instead of INNER JOIN users as **s**.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: that's one of the hell of query

Comment: I really hope that this is a fun project and not something you're doing professionally

Comment: would it help if I posted the table structure as well?

Comment: @zeiv, the more information you post, the better are the chances that someone will give you the right answer. Table structure, some sample data, and the expected (desired) output.

Comment: If it's double-quotes, then a *small* query -- say just the first `SELECT` -- should also error in the same way. Break your issue down into manageably verifiable chunks.

Comment: @AndrewLeach good idea, I'll try that now.

Comment: @AdnanShammout I added a screenshot of the table.  "I really hope that this is a fun project and not something you're doing professionally"  Why?  Is there something wrong with the approach I'm taking?

Comment: @zeiv: why not a stored procedure !!??

Comment: @Shades88 That's also a good idea, but I'd like to make sure the query works properly before I start doing that. Would I have to switch over to the mysqli extension in php?

Comment: @zeiv, buddy buddy.. buddy. We still don't get your problem. You see, what you're getting isn't some mysterious error. PHP is trying to tell you something. Help us make you understand it by making us understand your problem. Is it that last query you posted? did you try running it in PHPMyAdmin? what did you get?

Comment: I don't think the double quotes are what you wanted... that means you'd be selected the *string* "s.name" and not the *column* `s.name`

Comment: @AdnanShammout Well I started testing the query in phpmyadmin starting with the bottom subqueries and working up to the first... I found out there was a typo in the second subquery.  Ashamed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes mean you are selecting the *string* "s.name" and not the *column* `s.name`.

What you probably meant to do was use a backtick `. The backtick allows you to use reserved MySQL keywords as column names, e.g.

```
SELECT `table`.`name` FROM `table` ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your problem was a typo, let me take this chance to introduce you to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You know how everybody is telling you about SQL Injection and how scary it is? Well, with the right practice PDO can solve this for you.

This is bad:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=" . $uid . "");
```

and this is even worse!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=" . $_GET['uid'] . "");
```

Now lets do the first couple of lines of your code with PDO

```
//Getting the handle that will allow us to do stuff with the Database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid= :uid"
//Now we prepare our query, send it to the database server and get it ready
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
//So now we add the parameters to the query
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
//Now we execute it
$stmt->execute();
//Fetching the result
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Let's see our result
print_r($result);
```

and that's it! You wrote a couple more lines, but not only you protected your database, but you have yourself a chance of improved performance and be happy that you followed some good practice principles.

What you've just read isn't enough, make sure you check the PDO's documentation or at least this [good tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)